# How integrate $ \iint_{D} (\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2})dA, \ \ \ \ D: x^2+y^2=a^2 \ \ and \ \ x^2+y^2=b^2, \ \ 0<a<b $

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to resolve this integral

$$
\iint_{D} (\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2})dA,  \ \ \  \ D: x^2+y^2=a^2 \ \ and \ \ x^2+y^2=b^2, \ \ 0<a<b
$$

I tried with polar coordinates:
$$
x = r\cos{\theta} \\
y = r\sin{\theta} \\
Jacobian = r
$$

But I'm confused about in how to calculate the domain for each integral

Comment: Uhhh...then $D$ is simply the smaller open disk, unless I am missing something.

Comment: What is your domain (in particular, what is the symbol $\wedge$)?

Comment: the symbol $\land$ is the normal "and" that suggest it the intersection

Comment: Do you really mean $=a^2$ and $=b^2$? Inequalities would look less strange...

Comment: Maybe he means $\ge a$ and $\le b$

Comment: Well, the problem says so. I'm confused too, but the problem  is with $=$

Comment: If you actually have equalities, then you're integrating over the empty set, so the integral is trivially zero!

Answer (score 1):

if you are integrating over an annulus, then by symmetry
$$
\iint_{D} (\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2})dA = \iint_{D} (\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2})dA 
$$
so by adding you have 
$$
\iint_{D} (\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2})dA = \iint_{D} dA = \pi(b^2-a^2)
$$

Comment: How did you do that adding...?

Comment: You're missing a factor of 1/2, right?

Comment: hi Hans, the value is for the sum. i left it to OP to deduce the result, (if my reasoning was correct)

Answer (score 0):

This is just annulus with inner radius $a$ and outer radius $b$, so $a \le r \le b$ and  $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$. The integral becomes

$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \int_a^b \frac{r^2 \cos^2 \theta}{r^2} r\,dr\,d\theta 
\\= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_a^b r \cos^2 \theta \, dr \, d\theta 
\\= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2}(b^2 - a^2) \cos^2 \theta \, d\theta 
\\ = \frac{1}{2}(b^2 - a^2) \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1 + \cos 2\theta}{2} d\theta 
\\ = \frac{\pi}{2}(b^2 - a^2) $$